# Add a right-text in a input area

Tags: html, input

I must have this input with a text on the right.

So, it isn't a placeholder, it's a real input.

To do this, I must add a div for the text ?

I sought on the web but I didn't find any code :-(

[image]

Comment: `<input value="123">` http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_value.asp

Comment: did you look at this? http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups. i know this is bootstrap specific but similar can be written without bootsrap

Comment: Yes but I didn't use Bootstrap :-(

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `value="something"` and to pull it to the right, you need to add `style="text-align:right"`

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" style="text-align:right" value="abcd"><br>
  <input type="text" style="text-align:right" value="efgh"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Ok but I would like to start my input on the left and add my additionnel text on the right. How can I dissociate my input and my text ?

Comment: But it's just a text, it isn't a value which can be altered. If you just want a text to stay there forever then you can go with that.

Comment: On the right, I have a static text and on the left, I have the input area.